# How do I update table in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

To add the task, I did:

```
task = TaskList(task_name=form_add_task.task_name.data, doer=current_user) db.session.add(task) db.session.commit()
```

Now, user and tasks has one to many relationship. What I am trying to do in the UI is display checkbox for each of the task for the specific user(task_status column). If the user selects checkboxes(which could be one or many) and click on update button, I want to change the task_status to 1 by updating it.

How do I just update the task_status to 1 for a specific user if they select one or more checkboxes?

models.py

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    tasks = db.relationship('TaskList', backref='doer', lazy='dynamic')

class TaskList(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task_name = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    task_status = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

forms.py

```
class AddTaskForm(FlaskForm):
    task_name = StringField('task', validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_task_submit = SubmitField('Add Task')

class UpdateTaskForm(FlaskForm):
    task_status = BooleanField()
    update_task_submit = SubmitField('Update Task')
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/mytask', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def my_task():
    form_add_task = AddTaskForm()
    form_update_task = UpdateTaskForm()
    if form_add_task.validate_on_submit():
        task = TaskList(task_name=form_add_task.task_name.data, doer=current_user)
        db.session.add(task)
        db.session.commit()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first()
    task_list = user.tasks.filter_by(task_status=0)

    if form_update_task.validate_on_submit():
        if form_update_task.task_status.data is True:
        **HOW DO I UPDATE THE CHECKBOXES**

    return render_template('my_task.html', title='my tasks',
                           form_add_task=form_add_task,
                           form_update_task=form_update_task,
                           task_list=task_list,
                           user=user
                           )
```

Comment: An unrelated gripe: don't do `if form_update_task.task_status.data is True:` in Python, instead just `if form_update_task.task_status.data:`. `is` is the identity comparison operator, so you're checking if the object referenced by `...data` is the same object as referenced by `True` — which happens to work, because booleans are singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need something in your update task form to identify your task. Right now the object only has a boolean field but it has no way to tell flask or sql alchemy on which task should be updated. I would thus add `task.id` or, following your logic, `task.task_name` fields to the update form.

```
class UpdateTaskForm(FlaskForm):
    #task_id = IntegerField(#add relevant params here#)
    task_name = StringField('task', validators=[DataRequired()])
    task_status = BooleanField()
    update_task_submit = SubmitField('Update Task')
```

Afterwards i would use the `task.id` or `task.task_name` fields to fetch the task that needs to be updated from the database, set the `task_status` field to 1 and persist it.

```
task = TaskList.query.filter_by(id=form_update_task.id).first()
# or
# task = TaskList.query.filter_by(task_name=form_update_task.name).first()
if task is not None:
    task.task_status = 1
    db.session.add(task)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I am iterating tasks and putting check boxes in front of it. What I am having trouble is identifying those checkboxes. For e.g. There could be 10 tasks and user could have checked only 5 checkboxes. How do I identify those checkboxes and find the tasks.

Comment: you need to associate the textbox with the task.id or task.task_name through the checkbox "value" html property. When you are submitting the form to the server you have to pass a list such as `[{"id": <checkbox_value>, "checked": true/false},..]`  to the backend. Finally, you can use the data from this list to run the second snippet and "check all the boxes"